# Specify providers at service in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use Angular 2's DI system to automatically handle my services' dependencies. I'd like to use an annotation on the service itself, rather than using the second parameter of `bootstrap()` to specify all injectable services.

## What I've Got

A low-level service:

`services/role-store.ts`

```
export class RoleStore {
  constructor() {
    // Initialize roles
  }

  getById( id ) {
    // accepts id, returns role object
  }
};
```

A high-level service that depends on the low-level service:

`services/user-store.ts`

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {RoleStore} from './role-store.ts';

@Injectable()
export class UserStore {
  constructor( roleStore: RoleStore ) {
    this.roleStore = roleStore;
    // Initialize users
  }

  roleForUser( user ) {
    let role = this.roleStore.getById( user.roleId );
    return role;
  }
};
```

A component that depends on the high-level service:

`components/user-dir.ts`

```
import {Component, View, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';

import {UserStore} from '../services/user-store';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-dir',
  bindings: [UserStore]
})
@View({
  template: '<!-- inline template -->',
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class UserDir {
  constructor( data: UserStore ) {
    this.userStore
  }
  // other methods...
}
```

A root component to bootstrap:

`app.ts`

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

import {RoleStore} from './services/role-store';
import {UserDir} from './components/user-dir';

@Component({
  selector: 'app'
})
@View({
  template: '<user-dir></user-dir>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.css'],
  directives: [UserDir]
})
class App {}

bootstrap( App, [RoleStore] );
```

## The Problem

`bootstrap( App, [RoleStore] )` works, but I'd rather have an annotation in `user-store.ts` that tells Angular to inject `RoleStore`.

Something like `@Provide( RoleStore ) class UserStore {}`.

Any advice?

Comment: There was a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4154) that does this or similar, but it was closed as some kind of standby.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt make myself clear :(. That PR wasnt accepted. You could ask in that same issue if they will reconsider it.

Comment: @EricMartinez No worries, I understood you (I just did a poor job making *myself* clear ;) )! I'm sure it won't hurt to upgrade to alpha-44. If it happens to fix the issue, great. Otherwise, I'll look into the original issue and see if I can revive it.

Comment: Now that we're in beta I still have the same issue. I imagine a very large application with 100-300 services - are they all supposed to be inserted as parameters to the bootstrap proces?

Comment: I run into the same problem, and I would like that angular implement @Injectable for typescript , and add something like components has @Injectable({ providers: ['RoleStore '] );

Comment: So far, what I've been doing is defining providers in the `@Component` annotation: `@Component({
    selector: 'todo-app',
    providers: [TodoService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
  })`

Comment: Seems that there's no solution yet so far. You have to inject both manually in the component or module which is awful. I'd rather keep service dependencies information encapsulated in the service

Answer (score 5):

`providers` on services are not supported https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5622

What you can do instead is creating arrays of providers that are exported like "modules"

```
export const ROLE_STORE_PROVIDERS: Array<any /*Type | Provider | any[]*/> =
    [RoleStore];
```

and then in modules that use RoleStore service

```
export const PARENT_PROVIDERS: Array<any /*Type | Provider | any[]*/> =
    [ParentService, RoleStore];
```

and then use it in bootstrap

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [PARENT_PROVIDERS]);
```

I admit that is not what you asked for but the closest I found so far.

Answer (score 0):

You always have to register `providers` on some level, in your case it would make more sense to register them on the component level so that the dependency is specified there and not on the whole application level. Something like this...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'user-dir',
  template: '<!-- inline template -->',
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]
  providers:  [UserStore, RoleStore]
})
export class UserDir {
  constructor( data: UserStore ) {
    this.userStore
  }
  // other methods...
}
```

This is the official way of doing things that the dependencies are manually registered into Angular 2 DI mechanism on the most specific level possible.

That being said, you would need to write your own compile time / runtime (init) tool which would traverse code collect all @Injectable services and register them into Angular 2 context for you (by using `providers`)