# No provider for Token AppId

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, angular

I have a unit test that is verifying the application's APP_ID is a fixed value.  The problem is, I don't know how to set the APP_ID so that it's not randomly generated.

The documentation from the Angular2 team's website is helpful enough, but I'm not sure if I'm interpreting it correctly:

> If you need to avoid randomly generated value to be used as an application id, you can provide a custom value via a DI provider configuring the root Injector using this token.

So does this mean I'd add it as a provider in my app's bootstrap?

```
bootstrap(App, [
    provide(APP_ID, {name: 'MyApp'})
]);
```

I doubt that's remotely close.  Has anyone else figured out how to set the APP_ID or what it's even used for?

**injector.spec.ts**

```
import {
it,
inject,
injectAsync,
beforeEachProviders,
TestComponentBuilder
} from 'angular2/testing';
import {APP_ID} from 'angular2/core';


describe('default test injector', () => {
  it('should provide default id', inject([APP_ID], (id) => {
    expect(id).toBe('MyApp');
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In test

```
describe('default test injector', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => [provide(APP_ID, {useValue: 'MyApp'})]);
  it('should provide default id', inject([APP_ID], (id) => {
    expect(id).toBe('MyApp');
  }));
});
```

for your real application you would write it this way

```
bootstrap(App, [
    provide(APP_ID, {useValue: 'MyApp'})
]);
```

Comment: Nice, good to know I wasn't too far off.  Would it be possible to import the file where the bootstrapping happens, instead of duplicating the `provide(APP_ID, {useValue: '...'})` part in `beforeEachProviders`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36354220/217408 how to create providers and reuse them.