# How to inject list of classes from various modules in Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, typescript, angular

i want to create Angular 2 Modular app. All modules will be independent, but they won't have completely separate functionality. I have some problems with dependency injection, i don't know how to properly design it.

Example code:
Each module is created for another device (mobile, tablet, pc). 
Each of them have, for example, handler that looks like that:

```
@Injectable
export class PcDeviceHandler
  canHandle(type) : boolean
  { 
    return type == "pc";
  }
  handle(args)
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Core module has component with list of supported devices.

```
@Component([ ... ])
export class SupportedDevicesCmp
{
  handlers = [];
  handleDevice(args, deviceType)
  {
    for(let handler of this.handlers){
      if(handler.canHandle(deviceType))
      {
        handler.handle(args);
        break;
      }
  }
}
```

The question is:
How to inject all handlers from modules to this component?
Core module shouldn't know about these handlers.

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is that you try to solve. It might be something like I explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36354220/217408

Comment: Umm, I think it's not exactly what I want. In other programming languages (for example C# and autofac) it'll be something like that:
- In independent modules I create classes that implement interface IDeviceHandler
- Then, in main module I inject LIST of IDeviceHandler. As a result, I get all classes that implements that interface. After I create new class (new IDeviceHandler), main module will get it automatically on that list.

Comment: I had an idea to create a singleton 'storage' and all modules will add their handlers to that 'storage'. But how to do it? How to resolve that storage in each module on start and do something with it?

Comment: This is usually called reflection (for example in C#). I don't know how to do it in TS (I use only Dart myself). I assume it's possible in TS as well but reflection usually causes code bloat because tree-shaking can't know anymore what code it needs to retain and what it can prune.

Comment: What about multi-providers? Can I provide classes in different modules as one token and then resolve array of registered classes by that token?

Comment: You can provide classes as multi-providers. You can't access individual classes by name though. If you want to provide them globally instead of just on specific components you need to add them all at `bootstrap()` or your root component.

Comment: I think we're very close to solution.
How about that: I'll create singleton service for each module and add them at bootstrap(). Each service will somehow provide own 'handler' classes (as one token) as multi-providers. Then in main component i'll resolve all 'handlers' by token.
I don't want to access 'handlers' by name. I just want to iterate through them. 
Is this solution possible?

Comment: A service can't provide (DI's provide) anything. You can add them to an array in the service though and inject the service where you want to add components or iterate components.

Comment: Are services from bootstrap() auto initialized? I mean, is the constructor called immidiately after application start? For each module I can make 'module service', that depends on 'handlers storage service'. In constructor each 'module service' will add its own handler to 'handlers storage service'.

Comment: No, they are instantiated when first injected AFAIK.